# C# Passing Multiple Arguments to BAT File

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, command-line-arguments, process.start

I have this BAT file "iARP.BAT"

```
Content Begin
@ECHO OFF
npg -vv -f %1 -d %2
Content End
```

And I'm trying to pass a file name (in a loop) as the first argument and device name (variable previously declared) as the second argument. I'm trying to do this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < arpFiles.Count; i++) {

p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Application.StartupPath;
p.StartInfo.FileName = Application.StartupPath + "\\iARP.bat";
String argument1 = Application.StartupPath + "\\" + arpFiles[0].Name;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = argument1 + deviceName;
p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.Start();
}
```

BTW arpFiles = List
but it is not executing can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I'd recommend adding this line: `ProcessStartInfo si = p.StartInfo`, and changing your code to: `si.UseShellExecute = false;` etc.  Or simply creating a new `ProcessStartInfo` structure and using the initializer syntax: `p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() { UseShellExecute = true, /* etc */ };`.  Less repetitive :)

Comment: Why call a batch file that does nothing but runs another command?  Why not just run the command directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify them all in the `Arguments` property:

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", argument1, argument2);
```

Comment: I added this line and printed out the console output and it is saying the file can not be found but I can see it exists. I think the problem may be that the file path is too long because on the Error msg the entire filepath isnt shown it's trunc'ed

Comment: @GSUgambit - it's possible. `FileName` should point to the location of the batch file and `Arguments` should just be the passed in arguments.